# MySQL 5 min Moving Average (grouping rows by date ranges)

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I'm trying to get a 9 length moving average of 5 min prices from data that's in the following format:

ID, price, timeline

```
1   15.36573000 2017-08-31 22:00:00
1   15.29229000 2017-08-31 21:55:00
1   15.23297000 2017-08-31 21:50:00
1   15.23469000 2017-08-31 21:45:00
1   15.23234000 2017-08-31 21:40:00
1   15.25399000 2017-08-31 21:35:00
1   15.26228000 2017-08-31 21:30:00
1   15.21136000 2017-08-31 21:25:00
1   15.29847000 2017-08-31 21:20:00
1   15.32074000 2017-08-31 21:15:00
1   15.32239000 2017-08-31 21:10:00
1   15.27938000 2017-08-31 21:05:00
1   15.25282000 2017-08-31 21:00:00
```

So the averages for 9 time periods (45 minutes) would be:

```
8/31/2017 21:45 through 8/31/2017 21:05 = 15.26840444
8/31/2017 21:40 through 8/31/2017 21:00 = 15.27041889
8/31/2017 21:35 through 8/31/2017 20:55 = 15.27291889
```

I have seen a few moving averages by day but unable to determine how to group by the last 9 timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this in MySQL is via a correlated subquery.  Note that in the query below I don't count the number of previous data points, instead relying on the difference in time (40 minutes).  This would seem to make more sense, since perhaps your data does not always have the same number of points.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(t1.timeline - INTERVAL 40 MINUTE AS CHAR(50)), ' through ',
           CAST(t1.timeline AS CHAR(50))) AS window,
    (SELECT AVG(t2.price) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.timeline
         BETWEEN t1.timeline - INTERVAL 40 MINUTE AND t1.timeline) AS avg_price
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    t1.timeline >= (SELECT MIN(timeline) + INTERVAL 40 MINUTE FROM yourTable)
ORDER BY t1.timeline
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: that worked beautifully.  On a side note I realized for some reason i can't do this against a view for some reason (when i copied the data from my view to a table then it works... the same query running against a view however goes crazy)... I've been working on this for days though so not going to waste any more time trying to figure out why.  THANK YOU

Comment: Tim I figured out why my view didn't work - its because I have more than one ID -- how do i group by different ID's in that sub query?

Comment: I can't see you other/actual data, so I'm afraid that my answer is the best I can do right now.  You may _update_ your question with more information, but if it would completely invalidate my answer then you should really ask another question.

Comment: Thanks Tim your answer helped - if you were able to write that off the top of your head... lol well I hope to get there one day :D

Comment: Derrick - Did you get there now.